# Convert "mmmm d, yyyy" format into "dd/mm/yyyy" format with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, date

I have a bunch of data with strings of the format "mmmm d, yyyy", (for example: December 7, 2015 , or January 10, 2016). I want to convert these strings to dates with the format: dd/mm/yyyy (for example: 20/04/2012). However, I have not been able to find a way how to do this.

Your help is much appreciated.

[image: data]

Edit: I figured it out

My computer date time settings (windows 7) were European, whilst the date format "mmmm d, yyyy" is American. Basically what I did was change the operating system long date to be "mmmm d, yyyy" after which excel recognized the dates.

Here's a link if you do not know how to change the settings: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/software/how-to-change-the-date-and-time-on-your-pc-3267622/ look at step three.

Comment: Try something like this `=--A1` where A1 is the cell with the date.  Then format the new cell like you want.

Comment: Good find! You should post a self answer to explain how you solved this (instead of editing it into your question).

Answer (score 1):

- Highlight target cells
- Right click and select Format Cells.

Then you can use this window to make the changes[image]

Comment: I tried it on a computer with excel 2013 and this worked. However on excel 2010 it doesn't. Do you maybe know another method to make it work on excel 2010?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, the same window is in 2010. I have it there as well. Alternatively, since you have access to a 2013 version. Open the file there, make the changes, go back to your 2010 machine.

Comment: @D.Drako Are you *sure* the underlying data in the cells is excel date/time data? If you format the cell as a number it should be a 5-digit number, possibly with a decimal point. The formatting suggested in this answer won't work if the data in your cells isn't of this type. Further, it can't begin with a leading `'` character.

Comment: @Twisty no it is not, and does not display as a date. I uploaded a picture of the format on the main post